# A tool to automatically generate a UML diagram for a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml, entity-relationship

Looking for a good tool/gem that can automatically generate a nice looking UML diagram for an existing rails application.

(Im imagining such a tool would read the schema.rb file and then scan the models for relationships)

Comment: ProTip: If you can't get these tools working, double check your models and make sure you have all your belongs_to and has_many etc. matching up nicely between models.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Rails 3, try [Railroady](http://railroady.prestonlee.com/), it's maintained as well.

Comment: I switched to RailRoady from Rails-ERD (had problems with its rake tasks) - it has support for Rails 4 also.

Answer (score 17):

You could try [Rails ERD](http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/) as a an alternative to Railroad. It is maintained and works specifically for Rails 3.

Comment: Last commit 10 months ago, might not be maintained any more.

Answer (score 12):

RubyMine has a tool to do this; they call it a "model dependency diagram", but it generates a UML-like graph for your application models.

If you don't want to use RubyMine, check out [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/). It's a standalone tool that does similar, though RubyMine's is prettier, IMO.

Comment: RailRoad has not been updated in the last two years so probably not the best option

Comment: @Jordi Cabot exactly, I tried it approximately a year ago and it was not working

Comment: You could try [Rails ERD](http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/) as a an alternative to Railroad. It is maintained and works specifically for Rails 3.

Comment: @molf: Im going to keep the accept with Chris, as he was the best/only answer at the time of asking. But I'll copy your answer out to another Answer so the community can upvote whichever option is best.. (If u want points or something, you make your own and Ill delete mine if it's an issue). Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: In case anyone can't find this, here's the docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/viewing-model-dependency-diagram.html shift-option-command-u