# is there a gem that builds a visual diagram of your table associations/relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Something that generates an image or something to show that ModelA has_many ModelB etc?

Comment: +1 don't know of any gem, but that's an interesting idea. And to tell you the truth, yes, it just crossed my mind that it would an interesting small project :O

Comment: @SpyrosP im in on that if you're planning anything :P

Comment: RubyMine has this allready built in..

Comment: ahh, it seems that people did that already daamn :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [A tool to automatically generate a UML diagram for a Rails Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705995/a-tool-to-automatically-generate-a-uml-diagram-for-a-rails-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out about [Rails ERD](http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/).

Looks pretty awesome!

Answer (score 3):

[Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) can generate that for you. It is an awesome tool.

Comment: sadly i can't use it since i dont have many funds and my project isn't opensource...

Answer (score 2):

Try [rails_assviz](https://github.com/markmcb/rails_assviz) and [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/).

One more ancient plugin for zombie lovers is [Rails Application Visualizer](http://rav.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: railroad looks interesting but i cant make it run :( /Users/eumir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@waftt/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb:54:in `disable_stdout': uninitialized constant AppDiagram::PLATFORM (NameError)

Comment: i did railroad -a -M in the root directory of my rails app

Comment: also tried rails_assviz: rails_assviz/rails_assviz.rb:33:in `list_for_help': undefined method `to_sentence' for ["bmp", "canon", "dot", "xdot", "cmap", "dia", "eps"]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: There is something wrong with your environment. Try to use new RVM gemset

Comment: are there any gem dependencies?

Comment: im using rvm 1.9.2-head, is it incopatible?

Comment: I don't think there are any dependencies (there is no any info on the site). You can install `rvm install ree` and try to check railroad with 1.8.7

Comment: I have had problems with railroad too. From the documentation it looks awesome. But it does not seem maintained anymore. Latest version from may 2008 --> that is ancient :) I will try out the `rails_assviz` though.

Answer (score 1):

If using rails_assviz then you need to modify the line that loads active support to get it to work by adding /all to: require 'active_support'

Original:

```
#Checks for active_support
begin
  require 'active_support'
rescue LoadError
  raise "Install the Ruby on Rails gem: gem install rails"
  return false
end
```

Modified:

```
#Checks for active_support
begin
  require 'active_support/all'
rescue LoadError
  raise "Install the Ruby on Rails gem: gem install rails"
  return false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/intrica/ar_diagram to create visualizations of your models in development mode. You can make multiple views, save them and print them.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the website dbdiagram.io which allows you to quickly generate one using your schema.rb file

[Source](https://www.holistics.io/blog/visualize-rails-database-to-erd-diagram/)

Gif demo:

https://www.holistics.io/blog/content/images/2018/10/visualize-rails-erd-dbdiagram.gif